# How to delete a product with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to delete this product instantly when I click the delete button, so far when I click the delete button it hides the icon and the product is still showing until I refresh the page then the product is gone, how can I fix this?

Script

```
   function deleteFromFavourites(productid, userid) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: `product/${productid}/unlike`,
        data: {
            'user_id': userid,
            'product_id': productid,
        },
        success: function () {

    console.log($('#deletefavourite' + productid));
            // show delete button
            $('#deletefavourite' + productid).hide();
        },
    });
    }
```

Blade file

```
@foreach (Auth::user()->likedProducts as $product)
 <h4>USD {{$product->price }}</h4>
 <h1>USD {{$product->name }}</h1>

   <a style="display: {{$product->isLiked ? "" : "none"}}" id="deletefavourite{{$product->id}}" onClick="deleteFromFavourites({{$product->id}}, {{ Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->id : 0 }})">Delete</a>

@endforeach
```

Comment: also post the html part of your product

Comment: Check the updates @Poldo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must change to parent div of the product you want to hide instead of hiding the '**a**' tag.

```
function deleteFromFavourites(this, productid, userid) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: `product/${productid}/unlike`,
        data: {
            'user_id': userid,
            'product_id': productid,
        },
        success: function () {
            // remove parent division on success
            this.parent().remove();
        },
    });
}
```

in your blade wrap the product into div.

```
@foreach (Auth::user()->likedProducts as $product)
 <div id="parentDiv">
   <h4>USD {{$product->price }}</h4>
   <h1>USD {{$product->name }}</h1>
   <a style="display: {{$product->isLiked ? "" : "none"}}" id="deletefavourite" data-user_id="{{ Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->id : 0 }}" data-product_id="{{$product->id}}">Delete</a>
 </div>
@endforeach
```

Another workaround is to remove the onclick and add onclick function to your js.

```
$('#deletefovourite').click(function(){
   deleteFromFavourites($(this), $(this).data('product_id'),$(this).data('user_id'));
})
```

Comment: I'd also recommend to use ".remove" instead of ".hide" so the division for the product will completely be removed from the page.
I prefer doing it like: $(...).fadeOut("slow", function() { $(...).remove(); });

Comment: There is something strange happening , so lets say I have three products (1,2,3) so if I delete product 3 product 2 disappears and if I delete product 2 then product 1 disappears until I refresh the page, but if i delete product from the first to second then third it works fine why is this happening?  @Poldo

Comment: The one you just updated is not working, the button is not responding with this `deleteFromFavourites is not defined` on console  @Poldo

Comment: @joh add another parameter in function, should be working fine now.

Comment: The button is still not responding with these errors `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'this'` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteFromFavourites is not defined` @Poldo

Comment: Yeah I did add @Poldo

Comment: so where do I put those three lines is it under success or? @Poldo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201864/discussion-between-poldo-and-joh).

Comment: IDs have to be unique. Inside this foreach loop you should change the id attributes to class attributes, then change "$('#deletefovourite')" to "$('.deletefovourite')" and it will work.